# The connection's current state is connecting

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqldataadapter

I am writing web application in C#, and database is MSSQL Express 2012.

When i use `SqlDataAdapter` i get the Error:

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection.

The connection's current state is connecting.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn);
da.Fill(dt);
```

I can not figure how to fix it. Thankss

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: The language is C#, and database id MSSQL Express 2012

Comment: Add those tags to your question then.

Comment: Are you using OpenAsync to open the connection?  In which case you should wait for the Task that represents the open operation to complete before attempting to use the connection.

Comment: Can you please show the code, where you're opening the SQL-Connection (without ConnectionString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
lock(conn)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
    {
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: if not why don't you debug your application and check where are you getting the error.